# ReportDocument initialization is throwing an exception

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am writing this line of code

```
try
        {
         ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();  
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

and it is giving me the result

> "System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' threw an
>   exception. --->
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.LoadSaveReportException: An
>   error has occurred while attempting to load the Crystal Reports
>   runtime.  Either the Crystal Reports registry key permissions are
>   insufficient or the Crystal Reports runtime is not installed
>   correctly.  Please install the appropriate Crystal Reports
>   redistributable (CRRedist*.msi) containing the correct version of the
>   Crystal Reports runtime (x86, x64, or Itanium) required.  Please go to
>   http://www.businessobjects.com/support for more information.\r    at
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.CheckForCrystalReportsRuntime()\r
>   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument..cctor()\r
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r

any proper guide line ? i googled but didn't get any proper help.

Comment: Have you tried following the instructions in the exception? **"Either the Crystal Reports registry key permissions are insufficient or the Crystal Reports runtime is not installed correctly. Please install the appropriate Crystal Reports redistributable (CRRedist*.msi) containing the correct version of the Crystal Reports runtime (x86, x64, or Itanium) required"**

Comment: And have you checked the registry, as well as checking that you used the right redistributable for your app (in terms of x86/x64)?

Comment: would please like to guide me how to check that thing ?

Comment: Well, you should start by looking at what your application is running as - x86 or x64. I have no particular experience with Crystal Reports; I'm solely going by what's in the exception.

Comment: my application is running as x64